# SVG scale within a div from the center CSS

Tags: css, svg

While replacing some .png icons to .svg I'd run onto some problem, consider this:

```
<div class="container"></div>

.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("some-image.png");
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

In this case I had applied CSS transition to `container` and change its size (enlarge). Image inside the `container` onenlarge scales from center point inline with the container.

But when I changed it to .svg code (bellow) it starts to scaling from the left top corner. Does it possible to make it scale from the center of the `container` with my current set up (or at all)?

```
<div class="container"> <svg></svg> </div>

.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: 1s;        
}
```

// I already tried play with `transform-origin` all the way possible, applying it to the container/svg tag/and all elements inside it...

Comment: What CSS properties are you transitioning?

Comment: height/width, trough JS @enxaneta

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the problem as well as the solution**

All seems fine when animating only `height` and `width`, but some of my icons have `top` and `left` properties to animate to. And these ones are cousins the problem.

In my case it was looked like the `svg` is constantly "jumps" to the upper left corner while its container was resizing, but actually it was just snapping to the whole pixel value.

Animation of `top/left` properties are **not** subpixel, so in order to animate it smoothly it is better to animate X and Y, instead of manipulating them directly.

When I did so, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer** but I need to add some code. I don't see any difference. Please take a look. First I'm using two elements image.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/apple.png");
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s;
}

.svg {
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/apple.svg");
  left: 250px;
}

.container:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container svg"></div>
```

The second attempt: this time I'm using an svg element instead of a background image for the second div. No difference either.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/apple.png");
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s;
  
  overflow:hidden;
}

.svg {
  background:black;
  left: 250px;
}



.container:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="container svg">
  <svg  viewBox="41 54 106 122">
<g>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#ED1D24" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M143.099,93.757c0,0-14.173,8.549-13.724,23.173 c0.449,14.624,11.954,23.413,15.974,24.073c1.569,0.258-9.245,22.049-15.984,27.448c-6.74,5.4-13.714,6.524-24.513,2.25c-10.8-4.275-18.449,0.275-24.749,2.612c-6.299,2.337-13.949-0.137-24.298-14.987c-10.349-14.849-21.823-49.271-6.074-66.146c15.749-16.874,33.298-10.124,38.022-7.875c4.725,2.25,13.05,2.025,22.499-2.25C119.7,77.782,138.374,86.782,143.099,93.757z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#ED1D24" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M118.575,54.609c0,0,0.9,5.625-1.35,10.349
  s-10.718,20.936-22.994,17.999c-0.308-0.073-2.102-5.506,0.532-11.027C98.48,64.138,108.171,55.399,118.575,54.609z"/>
</g>
</svg>

</div><div class="container"></div>

<div class="container svg">
  <svg  viewBox="41 54 106 122">
<g>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#ED1D24" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M143.099,93.757c0,0-14.173,8.549-13.724,23.173 c0.449,14.624,11.954,23.413,15.974,24.073c1.569,0.258-9.245,22.049-15.984,27.448c-6.74,5.4-13.714,6.524-24.513,2.25c-10.8-4.275-18.449,0.275-24.749,2.612c-6.299,2.337-13.949-0.137-24.298-14.987c-10.349-14.849-21.823-49.271-6.074-66.146c15.749-16.874,33.298-10.124,38.022-7.875c4.725,2.25,13.05,2.025,22.499-2.25C119.7,77.782,138.374,86.782,143.099,93.757z"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#ED1D24" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M118.575,54.609c0,0,0.9,5.625-1.35,10.349
  s-10.718,20.936-22.994,17.999c-0.308-0.073-2.102-5.506,0.532-11.027C98.48,64.138,108.171,55.399,118.575,54.609z"/>
</g>
</svg>

</div>
```

Maybe you should edit your question and add more detail

Comment: I think I found the problem, can you verify? My actual timing for the transition is 2s, and seems like it stroking the animation. From top: 15px; left 15px; width: 30px; height: 30px; To top: 20px; left 20px; width: 40px; height: 40px; Strange and unexpected(comparing to .png)... on 1s all smoth @enxaneta

Comment: Please put all this in an working example. I really need to see the code in order to understand what happens

Comment: I found the problem as well as the solution, top/left animation are not subpixel so it is causing the "jumping"/not smooth animation of these properties. If animate x and y the problem is gone, thank you for the effort @enxaneta

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the CSS attribute `transform-origin` [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp)

```
div {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

`transform-origin: 50% 50%;` should center it.

Comment: As I stated in my question this one is no help .( @Zlerp